# Not able to use more than one Match functions

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I am not able to use more than one match functions in `filter()` of Query
where single match() working fine but when i start to use more than two match() it gives error like

> assertion failed: unable to use function MATCH in the requested
>   context: file
>   /Users/rspl/Desktop/Tests/SqliteSwiftDemo/SqliteSwiftDemo/SQLiteSwift/Statement.swift,
>   line 196

following example creates a problem:

```
emails.filter(  match("xyz", body) && match("wonder*", body))
```

is there any other alternate available ? or i made mistake.

I just want two simultaneous match from same or different columns.

Comment: did you mean `emails.filter{ match("xyz", $0.body) && match("wonder*", $0.body)}` ?

Comment: No, this filter is **[sqlite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)** library function

Comment: What is the return value type of `match()`?

Comment: Try `emails.filter(match("xyz AND wonder*", body))`.

Answer (score 0):

FTS only allows one 'MATCH' per SELECT statement. 
You can try this

```
emails.filter(match("xyz", body)).filter(match("wonder*", body))
```

Comment: this gives the same error message as above i have described. I think this statement give same as i have denoted in example(question)

Comment: Check out http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_1 — If you want to MATCH on multiple things, you just need to use `AND`, `OR`, or separate by a space. It's like searching on Google or other search engines. My suggestion: `emails.filter(match("xyz AND wonder*", body))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one MATCH in a Select statement, But you can use the following to achieve this,

`SELECT * FROM fts_table WHERE fts_table MATCH 'A:XXX OR B:YYY'` assuming that A,B are column names